# b-coefficient numerical value from pls r package

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, partial-least-squares

Has any body encountered a problem finding numerical values of b-coefficients while developing partial least squares regression model from spectroscopic data using `pls` package in R? If so, how could I get those numbers so as I could develop a b-coefficient plot using the numbers?

Answer (score 1):

After a conversation with the `pls` Package developer, I found out that the command:

```
plot(model, type = "coefficients", ...)
```

or `coefplot(model, ...)` produces a b-coefficient plot and there is no need to get numerical values for b-coefficients. An elaborated command like:

```
plot(model, plottype = "coef", ncomp=1:3, legendpos = "bottomleft", labels = "numbers", 
     xlab = "nm")
```

produced excellent b-coeffient plot for me. I thank Mevik, the software developer for the advice.